# String turned into a linked list then checking parentheses balance

Tags: c++, list, stack

So as an assignment I have to get a string from the user and turn it into a list and then check parentheses balance. However, I keep getting `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stacks>
class Node{
public:
char data;
Node *head;
Node *tail;
Node *next;
Node *node;

void addToList(char);
bool CheckList();
void StringToList(string, Node*);
};
Node* addToList(char data)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return newNode;
};

Node* StringToList(string text, Node* head)
{
    head = addToList(text[0]);
    Node *CurrentNode = head;
    for (int i = 1; i <text.size(); i++){
        CurrentNode->next = addToList(text[i]);
        CurrentNode = CurrentNode->next;
    }
    return head;
}
bool CheckList(Node* head)
{
    char c;

    stack <char> p;
    int i = 0;
    Node* CurrentNode = head;
    while(CurrentNode != NULL){

        if('(' || '{' || '['== CurrentNode->data){
            p.push(CurrentNode->data);

                 if(')' == CurrentNode->data){
                c= p.top();
                p.pop();
                if (c == '{' || c == '['){
                    return false;

            }
        }
            else if('}' == CurrentNode->data){
                c= p.top();
                p.pop();
                if (c == '(' || c == '['){
                    return false;

            }
        }
            else if('}' == CurrentNode->data){
                c= p.top();
                p.pop();
                if (c == '(' || c == '['){
                    return false;

                }
        }



            }
    }
    CurrentNode = CurrentNode->next;


}

int main()
{
    string text = "(check)[";
    Node *head = NULL;

    head = StringToList(text, head);
    if(CheckList(head)){
        cout<<"MAMA MIA IT WORKED-A!";
    }
    else
        cout<<"IT'S-A STILL WORKING!!!";

    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you again for your time. Also, sorry if my code looks a bit messy but im kind of new to stacks and lists.

Comment: Warnings are very good at pointing out the line number where problem code needs to be fixed. Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` minimum on gcc/clang, or use `/W3` for VS (`cl.exe`) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. Also consider adding `-Wshadow` to identify and shadowed variables that may be problematic. You can learn a lot from your compiler (though the STL warning spew is a bit much....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CheckList` claims to return a `bool`, but after the `while` loop and

```
CurrentNode = CurrentNode->next;
```

you don't have a `return` statement. The function just ends without returning a value. If a call to a function with non-`void` return type ends without a `return` statement (or prior exit via exception), the program has undefined behavior. The compiler is warning you about this possibility.

You need to add a `return` statement at the end of the function, with the value that you want to return. Given that the other `return` statements in the function all return `false`, I would assume that you intend to return `true` if the whole loop executed without returning `false`:

```
CurrentNode = CurrentNode->next;
return true;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function:

```
bool CheckList(Node* head)
```

doesn't have a `return` at the end:

```
    }
    CurrentNode = CurrentNode->next;


}
```

you must return something:

```
    }
    CurrentNode = CurrentNode->next;

    return /* an appropriate boolean value */;
}
```